# Converting Varchar into Date in data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, type-conversion

I am relatively new to SQL Server so I was wondering how to convert the data type from `varchar` to `date` format? I have a few thousands records so I need a query to help to convert the `varchar` to `date` in a single query.

I have the date in this format: `yyyymmdd`, in `varchar(8)` and I want to convert this into `yyyymmdd`, in `date` format.

Is there any queries to help me with this?

Comment: The `DATE` datatype doesn't have any *format* - it's just a 5-byte binary value.

Answer (score 1):

Simply Use this Inbuilt `CONVERT` Function, and Check this [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for formatting Dates

```
-- Use 101 if you have divider in your date
SELECT convert(datetime, '2014-01-02',101) as [DateTime]

-- Use 112 if you don't have divider in your date
SELECT convert(datetime, '20140131',112) as [DateTime]
```

**Edited:**

```
UPDATE yourTable SET field = convert(datetime, 'yourFieldName',112)
--This will update all of your field regardless of any particular row
--If you want to update any particular set of rows use `WHERE` clause
```

if you have more various formats goto to the given link.

Comment: I thought he might have missed, but both are provided now

Comment: @Kirk Hi, I have thousand plus records, your query above only can help me do 1 by 1, I need a query to do everything at once and update them? do you have any good suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Tell me what you want to do exactly? i'll rewitre here. btw instead of this `20140131` replace by your field name. ex: `convert(datetime, 'fieldName',112)`

Comment: @Kirk Thank you for your query, it works perfectly. Instead of selecting it, I want to update it. Is is possible to update it ?

Answer (score 1):

For various conversions between VARCHAR and DATETIME have a look at [this link](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLDateTimeFormats.aspx).

Actually in your case, since your VARCHAR is in yyyymmdd format, you could just:

```
convert(datetime, YourVarcharDateField, 112)
```

Comment: I have tried with this query, but it cannot work in my sql server, do you have any other good suggestion?

Comment: this is the error 'Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Comment: Then you have some values that are not in a 'yyyyMMdd' format. Can you run a query like `SELECT YourVarcharDateField WHERE LEN(YourVarcharDateField)<>8` and see what it gets you.

Comment: The mentioned error shows one of the following: 1) your data is not in mentioned format; 2) there're `NULL` values in the column; 3) you have not related data in the column (other text information). In this cases you need simply to filter the `wrong` (for conversion) rows and to decide what to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table] ADD ConvertedDate Date
UPDATE [dbo].[SysData] SET ConvertedDate = CAST(VarCharDate as Date)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table] DROP COLUMN VarCharDate
```

Comment: As of SQL Server **2008** and newer, I'd recommend using either `DATE` if you have date-only (no time), or then `DATETIME2(x)` if you need date and time. Avoid `DATETIME` - it's deprecated and has weaknesses (like the 3.33ms accuracy)

Comment: @mr_eclair I have tried with this query, but it cannot work in my sql server, do you have any other good suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Data types can be converted either implicitly or explicitly.
**Implicit** conversions are not visible to the user. SQL Server automatically converts the data from one data type to another. For example, when a smallint is compared to an int, the smallint is implicitly converted to int before the comparison proceeds.

**Explicit** conversions use the CAST or CONVERT functions.

The CAST and CONVERT functions convert a value (a local variable, a column, or another expression) from one data type to another

```
convert(datetime, '2013-05-04',101)

CAST ( expression AS data_type )
```

Comment: I have thousand plus records, your query above only can help me do 1 by 1, I need a query to do everything at once and update them? do you have any good suggestion? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CAST` **OR** `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to convert string to date

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST('20140102' AS DATE) AS convertedDate;
SELECT CAST(colName AS DATE) AS convertedDate FROM tableA;  -- Replace column name and table name
```

**OR**

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '20140102', 112) AS convertedDate;
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, colName, 112) AS convertedDate FROM tableA;  -- Replace column name and table name
```

**OUTPUT** of both queries:

```
|convertedDate|
|-------------|
|2014-01-02   |
```

Comment: Hi, I have thousand plus records, your query above only can help me do 1 by 1, I need a query to do everything at once and update them? do you have any good suggestion? Thank you

Comment: @user3146242 I had just give you an example. Using this function you can convert all records

Comment: @user3146242 Check my updated answer. It will do for all records in table

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I still cannot execute it well, it shows 'Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Comment: @user3146242 You're most welcome.. As per me there is some records in your table which won't follows `yyyyMMdd` format. Because of that you're getting error. Try to find that record and exclude that records from query

Comment: can you further explain? or what you mean is we cannot use the format yyyymmdd? if we cannot yyyymmdd, would you able to provide me a query to update to other format? initialy, the data we have is in yyyymmdd format.

Comment: @user3146242 I am trying to say that you had stored the data in `yyyymmdd` format but in some records this format not applied or some records which stored in database with some different format

Comment: Thanks for your explanantion, but all my records are in the same format (yyyymmdd). So do you still can think abour other query for me ?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL SERVER, there are two types of built in conversion techniques.

1. Convert
2. Cast

Convert having its own defaults so it will be outdated in upgraded version of SQL SERVER
better make use of CAST Conversion technique

In your scenario.Already having the date with datatype of Varchar(8) trying to Convert into  Date

Solve in systematic manner.

**Adding the one new Column in the existing table.**

```
Alter Table Table_name Add changedDataTypeDate Date
```

**Update the values in varchar datatype to Date Datatype**

```
UpDate Table_name Set ChangedDataTypeDate = CAST(OriginalDataTypeDate as Date)
```

**Again change the new column name into old column name.**

> Sp_Rename 'Tablename.changedDataTypeDate','OriginalDataTypeDate','COLUMN'

Its done.

**Based on u r requirement.**

```
Alter Table customer Add Purchase_Changedtype Date
Update Customer set Purchase_changedtype = CAST(Purchase_date as Date)
```

---

(If u need Time also replace Datetime istead of Date)

```
Alter table Customer Drop column Purchase_date
Sp_Rename 'Customer.Purchase_ChangedType','Purchase_Date','Column'
```

Comment: I am confuse in your query, do you mind if I provide my table name, column name to help me? My table name is customer and my column name purchase date